# Have the unit test "using" the project, or just have same namespace?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, visual-studio, project-structure

**Background**

I am working on a project with C# .NET, and I've just added a new unit test project to my solution in Visual Studio. The way that I always have been doing this is:

1. Create a new unit test project.
2. Have that project *include a reference* to the *project under test*.
3. Just *include* (`using`) the project.

I guess the other way you could do it would be...

1. Create a new unit test project.
2. Have that project *include a reference* to the *project under test*.
3. Make the *unit test* project share a namespace with the *project under test*.

**Question**

Is there an accepted way of doing this for projects in the .NET world, *or*, is this just an opinion and there is nothing more to it?

Comment: Using the same namespace just seems a way to end up with namespace conflicts. And you'd still need a reference to the assembly containing the code under test.

Comment: @DavidArno Yep, you're right I forgot about that. I updated the question.

Comment: I concur with David. Unless you're careful to explicitly name your test methods something different to the method under test, you risk there being naming conflicts. I just don't see how sharing a namespace brings anything to the party.

Comment: I concur.  Use a separate namespace for the testing.

Comment: @RobbieDee I could've sworn that once when I did "Create Unit Tests", VS went and automatically named the namespace to that of the *project under test*... Then I thought, well that's weird... So I changed it to [Namespace]Tests (in order to match the *unit-test* project-name). Then, I've wondered about it ever since.

Comment: @StevieV, but of course *everyone* uses the TDD approach, creating the test before the code, so the VS "Create Unit Tests" never gets used ... :) (in truth, I didn't even know VS had such a feature). I don't think there's a right answer to this; it's very much personal preference. But, as there's a small risk of name conflicts, I'd favour different namespaces as I don't think there's really any other compelling reasons to do it either way.

Comment: If they're written properly, tests should never conflict, since the method names will be something like `MethodName_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior()`, and I'm sure you could find suitable non-conflicting names for the test classes.  The real question is: do you really want those types showing up in your intellisense?

Comment: @StevieV Which version of studio are you using?

Comment: @RobbieDee VS2015

Comment: @DavidArno TDD is not applicable in every situation. If all my code does is go and read some electronic device and return a result (which is 99% of the time for EEs writing code)... All I care about is whether or not I get the right value, at that point it doesn't matter whether I write the test before or after.

Comment: @StevieV, my apologies, that wasn't supposed to be a serious comment (thus the smiley face), but I guess it didn't come across like that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The need for those dreadful bloated test method names stem from a number of things 1) Poorly named methods 2) Poorly arranged test libraries 3) Poorly written tests and 4) Shops that don't use BDD. Luckily things have moved on a great deal since those ideas were conceived over a decade ago.

Comment: @DavidArno I knew there was a joke involved, but there's always some truth behind jokes. And thus, I guess I thought you were implying to use TDD for *every* situation. I've yet to see where it could be of value when writing a library for a multi-meter (where all I care about is returning a voltage). At that point it becomes... So long as the meter returns a valid measurement, everything is ok.

Comment: @StevieV Ah, OK - the Create Unit Tests feature was something I saw in the early VS versions which was mothballed and then resurrected for 2015. I don't see it in my version...

Comment: @RobbieDee Very useful for when all I care about is... Send a command, get a certain response (i.e. an electronic device that a double-E might be using). I can write the test after, because all I'm doing is verifying that the communication involved actually works to get me my response.

Comment: @StevieV, I'm in agreement with you. Unit tests have their place and writing tests first does too. But I've found that trying to write unit tests for UI's, for example, is a waste of time and I can well believe the same applies to code that talks to electronic systems. Sometimes it's far better to have a real person do the testing than rely on automated checks.

Comment: @RobbieDee: *[shrug]*  I always saw those names as a convenience, not a mandate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your unit tests are in a separate project and serve a separate function from your main code, so putting them into a separate namespace makes the most sense to me.

If you're considering putting them into the same namespace just to save the `using` line, then don't. Less code is good, clearer code is better.

Comment: And you don't want to release/distribute/deploy unit tests.

Comment: Putting tests in a separate namespace ensures (in some languages) that you're seeing the API as a third party consumer would, i.e., not accessing members that are only accessible to classes in the same namespace. Conveniently, your tests will silence any spurious warnings about your public API members being unreferenced or unnecessarily exposed.

Comment: @TKK The question is about C# and in C#, namespaces don't work like that.

Comment: @svick: yes, and C# does not force you to give each assembly its own namespace. However, it is a useful convention, especially in larger projects, and I would not handle a unit test assembly differently than any other assembly on this.

Answer (score 5):

I've used unit tests project with the same namespace as the real project (by manually removing the `Tests` suffix on the test project namespace) for a few years with zero issues.

I think it leads to more straightforward code so I usually suggest going that approach. Some of the drawbacks, like potential namespace conflicts, just shouldn't happen when dealing with a unit test project since you are already following some test conventions for that, like suffixing all test classes with `Tests`. Additionally, to me it sounds quite intuitive to have the classes and the test classes in the same namespace.

Some people will think it's strange, but this really shouldn't be the case, as lots of framework assemblies also use this strategy of having multiple DLLs that have classes in the same namespaces: it is not supposed to be a surprising thing or a bad practice in and of itself.

I do think this one is more on personal taste though, so it's not really "answerable" per-se. Having said that, "my vote", as per reasoning above, is to try it for yourself at first, and if you like the approach, go for it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that doing the equivalent thing in Java is actually very beneficial, because there is the concept of package level access, besides public and private (packages = namespaces in C#). I.e. you can have package-level methods (hidden from classes in other packages) in your library under test that are accessible by your test class from the test library.